# jQuery(...).find(...).circleProgress is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a site where i need to include circular progress bar, for this i have used "circle-progress.js". If i run the site in normal HTML it works fine but when i am using WordPress it is not working and giving the following error:

```
function mycounter(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'counter', get_template_directory_uri() . '/circle-progress.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mycounter' ); 


jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function animateElements() {
        jQuery('.progressbar').each(function () {
            var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            var percent = $(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
            var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
            var animate = $(this).data('animate');
            if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() - 30 && !animate) {
                 jQuery(this).data('animate', true);
                 jQuery(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
                    startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
                    value: percent / 100,
                    thickness: 14,
                    fill: {
                        color: '#43C6DB'
                    }
                }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress, stepValue) {
                     jQuery(this).find('div').text((stepValue * 100).toFixed()+ "+");
                }).stop();
            }
        });
    }

    // Show animated elements
    animateElements();
     jQuery(window).scroll(animateElements);
});
```

> jQuery(...).find(...).circleProgress is not a function

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style($parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/style.css', false, 1.0, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style2.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

function theme_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/style2.css', false, 1.0, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/main.css', false, 1.0, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('align', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/align.css', false, 1.0, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('styletime', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/styletime.css', false, 1.0, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizrtime', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/modernizrtime.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', false );
    wp_enqueue_script('main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/main.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_load_scripts' );

function parent_css() {

    wp_enqueue_style('parent_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/template.css', false, 1.0, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('oldtemplate_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/angular-material.css', false, 1.0, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('camera', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/camera.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.easing.1.3', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.mobile.customized.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.sticky', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/jquery.sticky.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('media-uploader', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/media-uploader.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('options-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/options-custom.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('uslider.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/uslider.min.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('wow', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/wow.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('wow.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/wow.min.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-header', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/custom-header.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('customizer', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/customizer.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('extras', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/extras.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true




    );
    wp_enqueue_script('jetpack', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/jetpack.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('options-framework', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/options-framework.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('template-tags', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/template-tags.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('customizer', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/customizer.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('navigation', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/navigation.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('skip-link-focus-fix', get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);



}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'parent_css');

function mycounter(){

   wp_enqueue_script( 'counter', get_template_directory_uri() . '/circle-progress.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mycounter' );
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/avenue-child.php';
?>
```

Am i writing wrong syntax?please help.

Comment: I guees you are loading the `jQuery` after the `circle-progress` library which might be causing this error. Make sure that you're loading `jQuery` before your `circle-progress` library inclusion

Comment: My best guess would be, you are running above lines before loading the file `circle-progress.js` into `DOM`

Comment: i didnt get you. :( I am writing this code in functions.php file.

Comment: Can you please post the content of your `functions.php` ?

Comment: Looks fine with me.. however for `jQuery` you are not using a local file and your are hitting the `CDN` to serve it. Can you please check whether this link `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js` is blocked for you?

Comment: when i see page source, i cant find "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.mi‌​n.js" !

Comment: rest all the jqueries are there.

Answer (score 1):

Loading jQuery script after circle-progress caused the error.

Comment: I am new to wordpress.i am writing function mycounter() in function.php file and other jquery function in header.php.am i doing wrong?

Comment: just check the order of jquery with the help of view source

Comment: Yes circle-progess.js is loading after jquery function.How can i load it first in wordpress?

Comment: please send the order

Comment: order of each jquery?